# Simple leg animation in Farseer Physics

Tags: animation, xna, box2d, physics, farseer

I'm using XNA 4.0 with Farseer Physics 3.5 and would like to do a walk animation like seen in the game "Ibb and Obb" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2iif636QAcc. However there are many different animation when they're changing direction, standing still etc. I'm more than happy to be able to duplicate the run/walk animation

The player consists of, afaik, three bodies; the main body, and two leg/foot bodies. However I can't figure out which joints to use to make the legs move in a similar fashion.

Any Farseer/Box2D guru that might have an idea where to start, I'm clueless atm. Thanks!

Comment: I would be surprised if there is more than one body for the characters. It's probably just one body, with the moving leg parts just drawn over it depending on the current movement.

Comment: Just as the comment from @iforce2d said, I doubt the animation is really multiple bodies.  There does not appear to be any collision response, etc., related to the feet that is different from the entire body...they may not even be using a physics engine.